# How can I ignore the timestamp when pattern-matching "hdfs ds -ls" output?

Tags: shell, hadoop, sh

I have files stored on HDFS which have a date suffixed to their name, distinct from the modification date for the file, as shown below:

```
$hdfs dfs -ls /a/b/c/d/e/*
Found 5 items
drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2015-05-01 13:59 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2016-01-05
drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2017-10-10 15:42 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2015-05-01
```

I'm trying to find files only with a given `exp_dt`. Right now, efforts look as follows:

```
inputDir=/a/b/c/d/e/                                                                                                       
countCmd='hdfs dfs -ls $inputDir | grep '\.2015$''
hduCmdOutput=`eval $countCmd`
echo $hduCmdOutput
```

...which has the output:

```
drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2015-05-01 13:59 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2016-01-05 drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2017-10-10 15:42 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2015-05-01
```

Whereas what I **want** is:

```
drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2017-10-10 15:42 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2015-05-01
```

How can I prevent the datestamp for the file (the modification time) from matching, when all I want is to match against the filename itself?

Comment: This doesn't look like you actually want anything to do with regular expressions at all. Note that `foo*bar` is a glob-style pattern, not a regex, unless you want the `*` to modify the `o` that precedes it to match 0-or-more `o`s. (So `foo*bar` matches `fobar` or `foooobar`, but doesn't match `foo123bar`, when used as a regex).

Comment: ...speaking to the practices used here of putting commands in string variables -- see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describing why this is inherently buggy. Beyond that, it's not clear to me what your question is actually asking for.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2017-01-05 13:59 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2015-01-05<br/>
drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2017-10-10 15:42 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2015-01-05


Problem is if I have two results from hadoop fs -ls command as above , i want only the second result to be returned. I am getting both the results when I do the grep or find.
And is there any other way I can achieve this if its not possible in regular expression?

Comment: I didn't say anything was or wasn't possible with regular expressions; I said *you aren't using* regular expressions. Those are two completely different assertions. There is no regular expression (in the POSIX BRE/ERE sense) anywhere in `find . /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h*2018-05-01`.

Comment: Also, on UNIX, `find` doesn't filter its input stream; it ignores the input stream, and searches on the filesystem. Are you maybe coming from DOS/Windows?

Comment: I have updated the question, can you please check if you can understand now

Comment: Thank you -- I've updated it to make that still clearer for new readers. BTW, part of your problems are caused by quotes -- it's very important that you run `echo "$hduCmdOutput"`, not `echo $hduCmdOutput`; without the quotes, all the newlines are changed to spaces, runs of multiple spaces are printed by `echo` as only one, etc.

Comment: ...consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ for automated detection of that kind of bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Matching Your Specific Pattern

If you want to filter for the year only immediately after `exp_dt=` or `day_id=`, set up your filter only to match in that location:

```
hdfs dfs -ls '/a/b/c/d/e/*' | grep -Ee '(exp_dt|day_id)=2015-'
```

Or if you want to match `2015-??-??` only at the end of a line, that could look like:

```
hdfs dfs -ls '/a/b/c/d/e/*' | grep -Ee '2015-..-..$'
```

Note that there is no `eval` here. If you want to store this code to run it more than once (with potentially changed parameters), use a function for that:

```
filesForYear() {
  local path=$1 year=$2
  hdfs dfs -ls "$path/*" | grep -Ee "(exp_dt|day_id)=$year"
}
```

...can then be called as:

```
filesForYear /a/b/c/d/e 2015
```

or

```
filesForYear /e/f/g 2016
```

...etc.

---

#### Searching Only Filenames, In General

Consider the following function:

```
grepHdfsList() {
  local path=$1 pattern=$2
  while read -r line; do
    read -r _ _ _ _ _ _ _ filename <<<"$line"
    [[ $filename =~ $pattern ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done < <(hdfs dfs -ls "$path")
}
```

For each line read from `hdfs dfs -ls`, it extracts only the filename, matches only the filename against the pattern, but prints the entire line should that pattern match. (You could change `printf '%s\n' "$line"` to `printf '%s\n' "$filename"` if you only wanted to print the filename).

Invocation might look like:

```
grepHdfsList /a/b/c/d/e 2015
```

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls '/a/b/c/d/e/*' | grep -Ee '2015-..-..$' 
when i do the above command ,I am again getting multiple results , where I expected just one . It is searching in whole line instead of just  the last part.

Comment: @Babu, the `$` only matches at the end of the line. That expression *cannot possibly* match anywhere else, unless it's being run in a way or context that isn't actually invoking the command exactly as given (lots of ways for `eval` hackery to mess things up, f/e).

Comment: @Babu, ...that said, instead of just arguing about this, why don't you *show* me that regex matching where it shouldn't? For instance, you'll see that `echo "drwxr-xr-x - xuser xuser 0 2015-05-01 13:59 /a/b/c/d/e/exp_dt=2016-01-05" | grep -Ee '2015-..-..$'` correctly emits no output. Please give me a command I can run myself to see that `grep` behaving incorrectly

Comment: @Babu, I can't run that myself, because it requires `hdfs`. And I already told you not to use `eval`. Please provide something that can actually be run by people who aren't you -- there's a reason I gave an example using `echo`.

Comment: got it, Thank you Charles. sorry my mistake.